# Output pyowm weather as normal weather?

Tags: python, string, text, openweathermap

Couldn't find any info whether on the [*pyowm git*](https://github.com/csparpa/pyowm) nor else
While using pyowm, I use `print(weather.get_weather())` and so on.
Sadly the output looks like this, but I'm not surprised:

```
<pyowm.webapi25.weather.Weather - reference time=2018-02-23 16:55:00+00, status=Rain>
```

Pretty ugly.
I was looking for a way of deleting all that useless stuff and keep the word after `status=` which now appears to be Rain.

I know that something like `fileNameOnly = start[:start.find(ext) + len(ext)]` keeps everything 'till the specified character declared in `ext`,so I'd need a way to do the opposite.

Comment: I'd guess `weather.get_weather().status`. Actually, no; [`.get_status()`](https://github.com/csparpa/pyowm/blob/a609632ac7a43bc64f43c8b003473160a8e4277a/pyowm/webapi25/weather.py#L222). What you're currently seeing is defined by [the `__repr__` method](https://github.com/csparpa/pyowm/blob/a609632ac7a43bc64f43c8b003473160a8e4277a/pyowm/webapi25/weather.py#L378).

Comment: Wow, thanks for the help. I wondered... how do you keep track of all those questions and do like "AH! This was asked right here!"? It's impressive, means a lot about this Sites's efficiency!

Comment: In this case I just searched Google for `pyowm access status site:stackoverflow.com`, but there's a useful library of common Python questions at https://sopython.com/canon/.